# Mahout: using refresh function

Tags: mahout

How do we use refresh method in mahout framework to periodically refresh our datamodels? What does the parameter " Collection alreadyRefreshed" have to do with the refresh call, when it is never even used by the refresh function?

A link to the specific function in question: http://goo.gl/nwGzYz

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer finally through some experimenting!

The parameter for refresh can be set as 'null' as the refresh function automatically updates the datamodel based on the underlying file.